# Matlab axes resize in non interactive mode behaves unexpectedly

Tags: matlab, plot, resize

I am confused about how resizing works for plots with two axes in matlab. I am finding inconsistent behaviour in the result depending on whether I step through the graph generation code in a debugger (works properly) or if I run it all at once.

For example, in the following function, I am linking the Position property of my two axes:

- if I put a breakpoint on the last line, and step through it, the position of the first axis is changed automatically as it should be
- if I run it all at once, it does not change and gets misaligned with the second axis

What is the reason for this?

I am using 2015B if this matters.

```
function graph_test

% set up a horizontal bar plot with a scattre plot on a secondary x-axis
% at the top
barh(1:10)
ax1 = gca;
set(ax1,'Box','off');
ax2 = axes('XAxisLocation','top','Color','none','Position', ax1.Position);
linkaxes([ax1 ax2],'y'); 
linkprop([ax1 ax2],'Position');  
set(ax2,'Ytick',[]);
hold on;
scatter(ax2,[1:-.1:.1],[1:10]);
xlabel(ax1,'bottom axis');
xlabel(ax2,'top axis');


% set title
% we need to set this on second axis so that it does
% not overlap with axis legend
% the secondary axis is not auto resized as per matlab docs

title(ax2,'My graph');

% resize ax2 manually
ax2.OuterPosition(4) = 1-ax2.OuterPosition(1);

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are listening to changes in `Position` yet you are explicitly updating `OuterPosition`. The changes made in `OuterPosition` ultimately make their way back to changes in `Position`  but if the processor or renderer is busy, it is unable to propagate the change back (and notify listeners) until the processor is idle.

To fix this, you can explicitly tell MATLAB to flush all queued events immediately after changing the `OuterPosition` using [`drawnow`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html). This will cause `Position` to update and notify all potential listeners, which in your case will lead to the `Position` of `ax1` being updated.

```
ax2.OuterPosition(4) = 1 - ax2.OuterPosition(1);
drawnow nocallbacks
```

The reason that you don't see this behavior when stepping through it with the debugger is that, at that point in time, the MATLAB interpreter is idle and able to process all graphics events in real-time.